# Android App Development, Shared Preferences getBoolean Problems

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am developing an Android App and I am using a switch for the user to designate themselves as Male or Female.

I would like to use sharedPreferences to save the values they enter. I have successfully done this with simple buttons and text, however I cause the app to crash when I try to do this to the switch.

The line that cause the crash is `sharedPreferences.getBoolean("gender",false)`

here is the code (this is my load section):

```
private void loadSavedPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String firstnameString = sharedPreferences.getString("firstname", "FirstName");
    FirstName.setText(firstnameString);
    String lastnameString = sharedPreferences.getString("lastname","LastName");
    LastName.setText(lastnameString);
    String mailString = sharedPreferences.getString("email","Email");
    Email.setText(mailString);
    String postalcodeString = sharedPreferences.getString("postalcode","PostalCode");
    PostalCode.setText(postalcodeString);
    Boolean genderBoolean;
    if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("gender", false)) {
        genderBoolean = true;
    }
    else {
        genderBoolean = false;
    }
    genderSwitch.setChecked(genderBoolean);
}
```

Every other `sharedPreferences.getString()` works successfully.

Thanks,

Larry

Here is the logcat after I changed all that code to one line:

`genderSwitch.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("gender", false));`

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mobiquitynetworks.www.mobiquitymall/com.mobiquitynetworks.www.mobiquitymall.preferences_page}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2334)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
            at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getBoolean(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:261)
            at com.mobiquitynetworks.www.mobiquitymall.preferences_page.loadSavedPreferences(preferences_page.java:55)
            at com.mobiquitynetworks.www.mobiquitymall.preferences_page.onCreate(preferences_page.java:42)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT:

Here is how I save the boolean value using EDITOR:

```
private void savePreferencesB(String key, Boolean value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

Comment: remove the if/else statement and replace this line: genderSwitch.setChecked(genderBoolean); with genderSwitch.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("gender", false));  if its still crashing post your logCat, and show how you are putting the boolean into shared prefs.

Comment: It should work, clean your code and try it again. Unless you are putting that boolean field "gender" in the shared preferences as a String.   Are you writing to SharedPreferences like this?

Comment: sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("gender", true).apply();

Comment: @dhun I added how I saved it

Comment: okay, If there's ever been a string with that key ("gender"), even if by accident, it will stay there until you clear the app's data or uninstall. Try uninstalling it to see if it still occurs.

Comment: I actually switched to using Radio Buttons instead of a switch, for multiple reasons...    but thank you so much for your help! @dhun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand from the logcat is that you are trying to retrieve "gender" as a boolean, but it is stored a string.

So it throws an exception, look in the log cat.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
>               at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getBoolean(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:261)

try this to check if such an item exits, then retrieve and convert the string to boolean :

`Boolean genderBoolean;
     if (sharedPreferences.contains("gender")) {
        String temp = sharedPreference.getString("gender", "false");
        genderBoolean = Boolean.parseBoolean(temp);
    }
    else {
        genderBoolean = false;
    }`

Now, I would suggest in part where you save value to Shared Preference, you do it  this way :

`sharedPreference.edit().putBoolean("locked", true).commit();`

And in retrieval part, use this:

`if (sharedPreferences.contains("gender")) {
       genderBoolean = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("gender", false)
    }
    else {
        genderBoolean = false;
    }`

But, if you don't want to modify any thing, use the first option, but I suggest you do the second way.